# Can't vertical align multiple lines without huge line gaps

Tags: javascript, html, css, vertical-alignment, mixitup

I have a JS MixItUp, and I have it in text boxes, but I can't seem to get it to get multiple lines in a box, vertically aligned, and stay within the element.

To vertically align, I need to set the line-height and set vertical-align to middle.

I set the line-height to the size of the box (45px).

In this [this CodePen](https://codepen.io/jack-freiermuth/pen/rmQWNQ), you can see the problem on the bottom boxes -
 the words go right out of the box.

```
.courses span {
    border: 1px solid white;
    color: black;
    display: grid;
    font-size: 11px;
    height: 45px;
    background: #ffffff;
    border: 2px solid #505050;
    line-height: 45px;
    vertical-align: middle;
    margin: 4px 0;
    -webkit-transition: all .4s ease;
            transition: all .4s ease;
}
```

I also tried following [a vertical alignment example CodePen](https://codepen.io/CucuIonel/pen/espDH), but the single line would be at the top of the box.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some changes in css code.

Try this updated codepen:- https://codepen.io/bhuwanb9/pen/zwMJWj

```
.courses li {
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 14px;
    width: 19%;
    margin: 0.5%;
    background: #ffffff;
    border: 2px solid #505050;
    position:relative;
    height: 65px;
    box-sizing:border-box;
 }

 .courses span {
    color: black;
    font-size: 11px;
    line-height: normal;
    position:absolute;
    -webkit-transition: all .4s ease;
    transition: all .4s ease;
    transform: translateY(-50%);
    top:50%;
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Make the `position` of the box `relative` and courses span's `position` `absolute`. 
For example,

```
box{
    position:relative;
    display:block;
}

.courses span{
    position:absolute;
    text-align: center;
}
```

Try using these along with other attributes except `vertical-align` attribute in your code.

Comment: When I have position: absolute, it really messes up the functionality that I have in the Codepen that I linked. Not only that, the text still doesn't seem to be vertically aligned